# Adding a whole number to a date

Tags: date

I am trying to add the number 7 to the date an item is created in a list, which I want to display as the Due Date.

I have tried this formula in the DateDue column
=[DateCreated]+[DueDateCalc]
     where DateCreated is the column name of the field automatically created as today when the item is created and with type Date/Time
     where DueDateCalc is a whole number (in this case 7).

I get this error message
***The formula contains reference(s) to field(s).***

Can anyone help?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are trying to set a default value and that doesn't allow you to reference other fields when using default values.

You would want to make the default value of the column to be calculated and the formula would be `=[Today] + 7`.

Comment: Thank you so much - works perfectly - and I learned something!